# changing gnome-terminal look in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, gnome-terminal

I have ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop. I don't like the look and feel of gnome-terminal.
 [image]

See this screenshot i want change the title bar of tab name and add tab button and view tabs button at the right end. All of them ruining the look and feel of a terminal. I want them to be like in ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu 14 gnome-terminal screenshot below.
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/terminal-tabs.jpg

Comment: The differences are so small as to be **almost unnoticeable**... why are you worrying about them... you *must* have more important problems to solve with Ubuntu.

Comment: The original 16.04 release looked like the one you're looking for. A subsequent update maybe a month or two after its release changed its look. You could look around in the updates package for something fishy and try to downgrade them one by one. It could be the gnome-terminal(-data) package or some gtk+ themes or libgtk+ itself, I don't know. Also, the gnome-terminal I compiled for myself always looked like what you're looking for. I hope I could help, sorry if not.